# Flink standalone cluster: SIGSEGV crushing TaskManager

Tags: jvm, apache-flink, rocksdb

We have a simple standlone session cluster (20 TaskManagers) with several Flink streaming jobs.
Periodically (maybe couple of times a month) one of our TaskManagers dies with SIGSEGV error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8302eab031, pid=3947, tid=0x00007f82876f6700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_272-b10) (build 1.8.0_272-8u272-b10-0+deb9u1-b10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.272-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V [libjvm.so+0x5b6031]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid3947.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

hs_err_pid content is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/syamka/flink-temp/main/hs_err_pid3947.log)

As I understand, the problem is somewhere in native code and I suppose that can be RocksDB error (we use RocksDB as state backend in our jobs).
All information about similar errors in internet is pretty old, e.g. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8309
We use Flink 1.10.0.

I will be glad to any help or advice, I have no idea how to localize the problem.

Comment: If it's crash in rocksdb, would be better to get call stack with debug build.

Comment: The link that you mentioned says that the error does not happen with jdk 9. Are you using jdk 8?

Comment: Yep, jdk8 - flink 1.10.0 is compatible with this version
Conditions of my problem are not the same as in jira ticket - they have permanent problem on every checkpoint and in my case crashes appear occasionally. Thank you anyway for your comment, I'll think about changing JDK version